# Errors converting .ui to py files PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to convert my .ui files to .py files. I am using PyQt5 and Python 3.6.

When trying the below commands they all fail:

```
C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5>pyuic5 FirstApp.ui -o FirstApp.py
'"C:\Python35\python"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

```
C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5>pyuic5.bat -x FirstApp.ui -o FirstApp.py
'"C:\Python35\python"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

```
C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5>pyuic4 -x FirstApp.ui -o FirstApp.py
'pyuic4' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

```
C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5>pyuic4 FirstApp.ui -o FirstApp.py
'pyuic4' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I made sure that the `FirstApp.ui` file is in the same location as the `pyuic.bat` file and also added the paths to my Environmental Variables in system settings. I even reinstalled PyQt5.

I also tried to resolve the issue by editing my `pyuic5.bat` file located in `C:\Python35\Lib\Site-Packages\PyQt5` as follows:

Original script:

```
@"C:\Python35\python" -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

My edit: to point my bat file to where my Python directory is:

```
@"C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Then when I try running the convert command again I get a new error:

```
C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe: Error while finding module specification for 'PyQt5.uic.pyuic' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5')
```

I'm not what sure to do next to get around this very frustrating error. How can I solve this?

Comment: Try it: C:\Python35\Scripts\pyuic5.exe FirstApp.ui -o FirstApp.py

Comment: Hi S.Nick. my Python directory  doesn't have a Scripts folder.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is that you dont have the C:\Python35\ folder in your system path. Therefore the execution of pyuic5 cant find the python interpreter.